# Is there a function in JS to check if a string is an english word?

Tags: javascript

Im working on a chrome extension, and I will get a string from the webpage but I need to check if that word is a valid English word. I dont even need the meaning of the word, just check in JS if the string is a valid word. I already achieved this in Python using enchant library, but I cant seem to find a way to achieve it in JavaScript. Any ideas?

Example:
String: WUELUA
Output: not a word

String: HELLO
output: is a word

Comment: This is not something you can do statically, so your best bet is to look for an API that provides such service

Comment: Download a dictionary, convert to array, pray it's sorted correctly and binary search :) (tl;dr no unless you want to use an API or similar - nothing built-in)

Comment: Use https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js

Comment: If you are able to do it in python, then create a rest API  in python & send queries to it.

Comment: The least you can do in vanilla JS is check whether it contains valid English letters. Like, H3llo, Output : Not a word, Sjdjj, Output : has valid letters

Comment: So the question is asking us to recommend a JavaScript library to replace the enchant library?

Comment: @User863 right answer right here